# Storing information about users in other parts of the project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Using EF and Asp .Net Identity in an MVC 5 project. I would like to associate records in the database with particular users. The problem is, I have two separate DbContexts. ApplicationDbContext handles Identity functions: authentication, authorization, etc... My other DbContext (MyDbcontext) handles the actual business of the application. I would like to associate records in MyDbContext with users in ApplicationDbcontext. Do I need to open ApplicationDbContext, get my user info, close it, then open MyDbContext and perform some work? Can I open both at the same time? Do I need some kind of mapping table in MyDbcontext? For a bonus, can I get user info in my EF migrations seed method for MyDbContext?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your app context inherit from identity context, but assuming you don't want to do that the next best option would be to configure a copy of the user model in your app context and add the `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` to your app context. You could also just store updatedBy and createdBy without doing a relation.